Excel Data input or Graph
how to visualize uniaxial cyclic loading 0→(ε=0.02↔ ε=-0.005) x20 cycleenter image description here
somewhat like this but strain control is 2% and -0.5%
stress strain graph for cyclic loading mechanical splice
Cycles of loading for the inelastic cyclic endurance test shall be inelastic strain cycles between 2 percent strain in tension and 0.5 percent strain in compression, where the strain shall be measured in the reinforcing bar adjacent to but not including the mechanical splicing device.
example for mechanical splice bar grade 550
